# Artifacts on lollipop popup menu when using dark background

Tags: android, android-5.0-lollipop

As you can see the background is distorted behind the popup.  It only happens on lollipop! Please don't be confused by all the x_ in my style files. I've just de-branded the code.

[image: With dark background on popup]

In theme file:

```
 <style name="core" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light">

    <!-- Popup menu -->
    <item name="android:popupMenuStyle">@style/x_popup_menu_theme</item>
    <item name="android:textAppearanceSmallPopupMenu">@style/x_popup_menu_small_text</item>
    <item name="android:textAppearanceLargePopupMenu">@style/x_popup_menu_large_text</item>

</style>
```

in v21/themes_styles.xml

```
<style name="x_popup_menu_theme" parent="Widget.AppCompat.PopupMenu">
    <item name="android:popupBackground">@color/x_navy_dark</item>
</style>

<style name="x_popup_menu_large_text" parent="TextAppearance.AppCompat.Widget.PopupMenu.Large">
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/std_white</item>
</style>

<style name="x_popup_menu_small_text" parent="TextAppearance.AppCompat.Widget.PopupMenu.Small">
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/std_white</item>
</style>
```

If I change/remove the style to this it works as shown in the next pic.

[image: With light background on popup]

```
<style name="x_popup_menu_theme" parent="Widget.AppCompat.PopupMenu">
</style>

<style name="x_popup_menu_large_text" parent="TextAppearance.AppCompat.Widget.PopupMenu.Large">
</style>

<style name="x_popup_menu_small_text" parent="TextAppearance.AppCompat.Widget.PopupMenu.Small">
</style>
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There was a bug in Android 5.0.x (which was fixed in 5.1) where setting an opaque (ex. `@color`) background in an elevated window resulted in visual artifacts.

As a workaround on 5.0.x devices, you can set the background to a non-opaque drawable such as a rounded rectangle.

res/drawable/my_popup_bg.xml:

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
       android:shape="rectangle">
    <corners android:radius="2dp" />
    <solid android:color="@color/x_navy_dark" />
</shape>
```

res/values/styles.xml:

```
...

<style name="x_popup_menu_theme" parent="Widget.AppCompat.PopupMenu">
    <item name="android:popupBackground">@drawable/my_popup_bg</item>
</style>
```

Answer (score -1):

[EDITED - Removed original answer that suggested turning off hardware acceleration]

It appears this is a bug in android 5.0 with the frame buffer. It has been fixed in android 5.1. [Bug listing](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=165564)

Here's a message from Chet Haase on how to work around the issue:

> The trigger is that you're setting the background of the popup window to a color, which resolves to a colored rectangle. You should either be using a rounded rect (like the default style uses) or, better yet, use the dark theme instead of a custom color.
>   The bug [in android] (which is [fixed in 5.1]) was that we were not accounting for the padding for shadows and were not setting the correct translucency flags in the window in this situation.

For now I just created my own popup menu using a linearlayout and handling the clicks and back button manually. Not too elegant, but it matched what the art team wanted closer than the popup menu anyway.

[image: My finished popup]

```
           <LinearLayout
                android:id="@id/fake_popup"
                android:layout_below="@id/pending"
                android:visibility="gone"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:orientation="vertical">
                <TextView
                    style="@style/button.dropdown"
                    android:id="@id/send_reminder"
                    android:background="@color/navy_dark"
                    android:textColor="@color/std_white"
                    android:text="@string/send_reminder"/>
                <TextView
                    style="@style/button.dropdown"
                    android:id="@id/withdraw_invite"
                    android:background="@color/navy_dark"
                    android:textColor="@color/std_white"
                    android:text="@string/withdraw_invite"/>

            </LinearLayout>
```

Handle the click to show/hide the menu (note the annotations are ButterKnife):

```
    @OnClick (R.id.pending) public void showPendingActionsMenu () {
    // pendingActionsPopupMenu.show ();

    if (pendingPopup.isShown ()) {
        hidePendingPopup ();
    } else {
        showPendingPopup ();
    }
}
```

And handle the clicks of the individual choices:

```
@OnClick (R.id.send_reminder)
public void sendReminder () { //your code here }
```

Don't forget to override onBackPressed!

```
@Override public void onBackPressed () {
    if (pendingPopup.isShown ()) {
        hidePendingPopup ();
    } else {
        super.onBackPressed ();
    }
}
```

Comment: You really shouldn't solve this by disabling hardware acceleration, as that 1) degrades the performance of your app and 2) disables shadows. Follow Chet's suggestions.

Comment: I agree that's why I have Chet's suggestions in the solution.